# Multiple instances in google compute

Tags: google-compute-engine

Using instance groups, can one combine multiple-processors and then assign a that is distributed computing across them.

How can one assign a computing job to instance group?

How would this be different from one instance with multi processors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can accomplish distributed processing on GCE, much like you would on an equivalent physical infrastructure. A good example of this can be found here [1](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/). This was you can achieve far higher computation power (in the form of computation nodes) than you could with multi-threaded, multi-core processing on a single system. Add to that auto-scaling capabilities, and you can set up an adaptive, parallel computation cluster. Further reading: [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/)